# Ubuntu 14.04.1 Stopped Detecting Wifi in laptop

Tags: wireless, ralink, detect, wifi-hardware-switch

I am having a huge trouble with ubuntu 14.04. The Ubuntu unable to detect wireless adapter in My laptop earlier there was no Issue with it My wifi works well . I dont know what had gone wrong  there is no wrong/broken package in ubuntu. Even my system is Updated and I have also tried it using "rfkill list" command but the main headache is rfkill doesnt shows the List of devices at all.

I had also gone to additional drivers page it shows that the "drivers are not avaliable". Also i have tried the WIFI switch but still it doesnt shows up.

"Rfkill list"Command shows no output at all

and when i enter the command iwconfig then it shows "no wireless extension"

My laptop is compaq notebook 15 it has ralink wifi and Bluetooth

I want to use wifi please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what going on with your WiFi connection but have you added the correctly driver for you Ubuntu system?

You can check to see if your wireless drivers are being detected by opening up your **Software & Update manage** and click on **Additional Drivers**

There should be a list of appropriate drivers you can choose for your system

But if you can gain access to the internet try connecting your computer using a **Land cable** once you do this it will allow you to search online and find the correct drivers you need.